# Becker, Becker, Schwarz: "String Theory and M Theory" Exercise 5.3

Tags: homework-and-exercises, supersymmetry, dirac-matrices, majorana-fermions, grassmann-numbers

Supersymmetric transformation:
$$
\begin{align}
\delta\Theta^{Aa} =& \varepsilon^{Aa}, \tag{5.3} \cr
\delta X^\mu =& \bar{\varepsilon}^A\Gamma^{\mu}\Theta^A. \tag{5.4}
\end{align}
$$
The combination
$$\Pi^\mu_\alpha := \partial_\alpha X^\mu 
  - \bar{\Theta}^A\Gamma^\mu\partial_\alpha\Theta^A,\tag{5.7} $$
is changed as
\begin{align}
\delta\Pi^\mu_\alpha
&= \partial_\alpha(\delta X^\mu)
 - \delta\bar\Theta^A\Gamma^\mu\partial_\alpha\Theta^A
 - \bar\Theta^A\Gamma^\mu\partial_\alpha\delta\Theta^A\nonumber\\
&= \partial_\alpha(\bar\varepsilon^A\Gamma^\mu\Theta^A)
 - \bar\varepsilon^A\Gamma^\mu\partial_\alpha\Theta^A
 - \bar\Theta^A\Gamma^\mu\partial_\alpha\varepsilon^A\nonumber\\
&= \partial_\alpha\bar\varepsilon^A\Gamma^\mu\Theta^A
 + \bar\varepsilon^A\Gamma^\mu\partial_\alpha\Theta^A
 - \bar\varepsilon^A\Gamma^\mu\partial_\alpha\Theta^A
 + \partial_\alpha\bar\varepsilon^A\Gamma^\mu\Theta^A.
\end{align}

I think $2\partial_\alpha\bar\epsilon^A\Gamma^\mu\Theta^A$ left and not supersymmetric.

Is the above calculation wrong?

P.S.
I rethought and noticed it maybe a global transformation and the parameter $\varepsilon$ is spacetime independent.
If so, the above deformation is zero and supersymmetry is satisfied.
Do you agree with it?

Comment: If you read the two sentences above (5.6) and one sentence below (5.7) your question will be answered.

Comment: Thanks! I understood

Comment: @KoKo_physmath if the answer solves your problem, I would recommend "accepting" it by clicking on the grey checkmark

Answer (score 1):

OP's calculations are correct because of the rule $\bar{\Theta}_1\Gamma^{\mu}\Theta_2=-\bar{\Theta}_2\Gamma^{\mu}\Theta_1$ for 2 Grassmann-odd Majorana spinors, cf. Exercise 5.1.

And OP is correct that the offending term $\partial_\alpha\bar{\epsilon}^A=0$ vanishes because the SUSY is assumed to be **global.**

Comment: Thanks I got it. :D